# Need to prevent default jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to stop a form (add to cart) from submitted assuming that a cookie is not set

```
jQuery('input[name=addtocart]').click(function() {  
    ...
switch(curr_active_table){
      case '1': {
        ...
    alert(" Please select a Lense Option first before Adding to cart");
                event.preventDefault();
    break;  
}
```

...

Everything works like a champ till I get to the point I need to stop the even from being submitted

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass in the [event] argument

```
jQuery('input[name=addtocart]').click(function(event) {  //<-- see event inside function()
    ...
switch(curr_active_table){
      case '1': {
        ...
    alert(" Please select a Lense Option first before Adding to cart");
                event.preventDefault();
    break;  
});
```

then force enter key default to click action

```
jQuery('form').keypress(function(event) {  //<-- listen for keypress inside form
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // <-- if enter default to click action 
        jQuery('input[name=addtocart]').click();//<- trigger click action
        return false;// or event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

as you can see here in this fiddle.. that will prevent enter key inside the form from submitting

http://jsfiddle.net/8mYnN/1/

@Juan Mendes - Ok now I understand what you're saying.. you don't need to listen for enter keypress if you just do everything in the submit event of the form

```
jQuery('formselector').submit(function(event) {  //<-- see event inside function()
        ...
    switch(curr_active_table){
          case '1': {
            ...
        alert(" Please select a Lense Option first before Adding to cart");
                    event.preventDefault();
        break;  
 });
```

Comment: This will not prevent submission if the form is submitted using the enter key

Comment: You should revise the answer to clarify that you should not use the first two examples

Answer (score 1):

Wirey's answer works, an alternative is to return false from the handler http://jsfiddle.net/aWPKp/

```
$('input[name=addtocart]').click(function(){
  return false;    
});​
```

**UPDATE** Since this is a form submit, you should handle the submit event so that it also works when you hit enter on the submit button. http://jsfiddle.net/aWPKp/1/

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
  return false;    
});​
```

Comment: wouldn't that prevent form submission all together?

Comment: @wirey Yes it would. Just add as much code as you want around that `return false` :)